# Is there some way to distinguish between users of different organization in a Microsoft Teams bot?

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azureportal

> I want to know the organization of user in teams-bot. I have registered my application on azure portal as a multi-tenant application.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "organization"? Is the user's TenantId sufficient? If so, that's pretty easy to get so I can explain, but want to confirm. Also, what language is your bot written in, in case there are code snippets I can send.

Comment: I am allowing multiple company users on my app. So I want to know, is there some way to know the company of user in teams bot.

Comment: What I mean is, do you need to know the actual company name? Is it enough to know which tenant id the user is coming from?

Comment: Tenant id is enough. But is there any way to know the actual company name ?

Comment: I wrote my bot in typescript.

Comment: I just realised what I had in mind won't work. Basically, when you get a message sent to the bot, it includes a tenant id, but it's always the tenant of the conversation, no matter what user it is.

Comment: I even tried getting the conversation members, because it brings back a tenantid for each user, but it also always brings back the same tenant. Even a guest user has a upn in the main tenancy in order to be a guest, so it's bringing that back, just for information.

Comment: Anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: sure, sorry I couldn't help more

Answer (score 1):

The only way to distinguish between members of different organization using the bot framework is to compare tenant ids. You can access the tenantID by using the team member info mapped to the TeamsChannelAccount object [seen here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/18f6bc8777f19128ebc15123fa2af804d8c3e793/libraries/botframework-connector/src/teams/models/mappers.ts)

You can access this object using [teamsInfo.getMembers](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder/src/teamsInfo.ts#L42)

In the bot code, it would look something like this:

```
async messageAllMembersAsync(context) {
    const members = await TeamsInfo.getMembers(context);

    members.forEach(async (teamMember) => {
        const test = teamMember;
        const message = MessageFactory.text(`Hello ${ teamMember.givenName } ${ teamMember.surname }. I'm a Teams conversation bot.`);

        var ref = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
        ref.user = teamMember;

        await context.adapter.createConversation(ref,
            async (t1) => {
            const ref2 = TurnContext.getConversationReference(t1.activity);
            await t1.adapter.continueConversation(ref2, async (t2) => {
            await t2.sendActivity(message);
        });
    });
});
```

This is the information it returns:

[image: teams channel account object]

If you want to say, compare company names, you can access the `teamMember.userPrincipalName` or `teamMember.email` properties and compare the @companyname.com portion of the emails as well.

Comment: I tested this earlier today, thinking the same, but both my regular user and my guest user had the same tenant id. The guest obviously had a UPN matching the main tenancy, but based on his/her external UPN. Are you seeing something different?